# Display all windows on internal display if external is connected but off?

Tags: display

I have placed some windows on my external display. However, whenever the external display is connected but turned off, those windows do not appear on the internal display and I cannot reach them without either turning on the external screen or disconnecting the display.

Is there a software workaround to always display windows that have been placed on the external display on the internal one if the external display is connected but turned off?

Comment: It's probably outdated advice (I don't have a gather windows button anymore), but it has linked questions that might be helpful. Please [edit] your question when you've tried them and it didn't work for you, such that others don't spend time suggesting something that you don't find helpful.

Comment: By turn off, do you mean the external display is put into some kind of sleep mode or its plug pulled out?